# this find parent of another div and toggle its child using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done some research and nothing seems to be working.  Here is the HTML followed by the JavaScript I am putting together.  What I am trying to do is set it up so that whenever dashboard_gear_options is clicked, it toggles the appropriate hidden options row.  Each block of code exists multiple times at different locations on the page.  I tried using this, find, parent, next and children to no avail.

HTML:

```
// start block
<div class="content_block_holder">
   <div class="content_top">
      <div class="dashboard_gear_options"></div>
      <div class="dashboard_gear_divider"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="dashboard_holder">
      <div class="hidden_options_row"></div>
   </div>
</div>
// end block

// start block
<div class="content_block_holder">
   <div class="content_top">
      <div class="dashboard_gear_options"></div>
      <div class="dashboard_gear_divider"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="dashboard_holder">
      <div class="hidden_options_row"></div>
   </div>
</div>
// end block (etc..)
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.dashboard_gear_options').click(function(){
       $(this).parent('.content_block_holder').find('.hidden_options_row').toggle();        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `closest([selector])` ( http://api.jquery.com/closest/ ) instead of parent in your selector. It will traverse up the tree and find "content_block_holder". `parent([selector])` will just check the immediate parent and return an empty set if it doesn't match the selector provided.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.dashboard_gear_options').click(function(){
       $(this).closest('.content_block_holder').find('.hidden_options_row').toggle();        
   });
});
```

JSFiddle based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/gK7yM/

Comment: That did it, I had tried that one to on a different configuration :(  It's always the simple things..thank you much!  I can mark it yet as correct but I will when the timer is up.

Comment: Well, trying and experimenting with different configurations is the best way to learn, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(this).closest('.content_block_holder').find('.dashboard_holder').find('.hidden_options_row').toggle();
```

Comment: It is actually the parent but not the immediate parent, so closest would be more suitable

Answer (score 0):

[Also this chain works](http://jsfiddle.net/gJCcw/):

```js
$(this).parent().next('.dashboard_holder').children('.hidden_options_row').toggle();
```

or

```js
$(this).parent().next('.dashboard_holder').find('.hidden_options_row').toggle();
```